# How do I make a Frame in tkinter disappear and reappear without making another Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I'm working with `Tkinter` and using `pack` to manage `Frame`. How can I visually make a `Frame` disappear without deleting it or making it invisible? I want `the` Frame underneath to fill the space, and later, I want the hidden `Frame` to reappear with the other `Frame` moving back into place. Let me **clarify**, I tried the other answers, but they don't suit my needs. I use python 3.11.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `pack`, then you can use `pack_forget` to make the frame disappear. You can then use `pack` again to make it reappear. You have to make sure that when you call `pack` a second time that you put it back in the proper spot. `grid` is much better for this since grid has a way of remembering how a widget was added to the screen.

Here's an example using `pack`:

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle():
    if top_frame.winfo_viewable():
        top_frame.pack_forget()
    else:
        top_frame.pack(before=bottom_frame, fill="x")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

top_frame = tk.Frame(root, background="bisque", height=100)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(root)
toggle_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Toggle", command=toggle)

top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
toggle_button.pack(side="bottom", padx=20, pady=20)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot with top frame visible]

[image: screenshot with top frame hidden]

Comment: I'm testing this out, I think it might be right.